Unrecognized arguments error while converting tensorflow model to onnx by tf2onnx
I'm trying to convert tensorflow model to onnx using tf2onnx.
While running the
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model /dir/tf_model --output /dir/model.onnx --verbose

(dir = directory for my custom model), I got error convert.py: Error: Unrecognized arguments; /dir/tf_model
Before the error, I also got
RuntimeWarning: "tf2onnx.convert' found in sys.modules after import of pacakge 'tf2onnx', but prior to execution of 'tf2onnx.convert'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour

I'm really trying to figure out why this warning and error occur, but still got no answer....
I really need your advice and help
I double checked the directory of model in my ubuntu, which is always same.
Also, downgrade tf2onnx version from 1.14.0 to 1.9.3 which is supported for tensorflow 2.7.0

Hardware: Jetson Nano Developer Kit B01 4GB RAM
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Python: 3.6.9
Tensorflow: 2.7.0
Keras: 2.7.0
tf2onnx: 1.9.3
onnx: 1.11.0
onnxruntime-gpu: 1.11.0
